# Placing an element under another vertically centered

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```css
 #div1 {
     height:100px;
     width:200px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     position: fixed;
    }
    
    #field{
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    
    #dp a{display:block;}
```

```html
    <div id= "div1">
    <div id="field"><input placeholder="Type something...." ></div>
    <div id="dp"><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a> </div>
    </div>
```

here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

The yellow part is a simple drop-down that has to be displayed on focus, and fit the input element's width. I've made lots of attempts, but I got stuck with placing the drop down just under the centered input's parent div element.

Comment: You use js for dropdown?

Comment: This looks like a use-case for a [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element, or an [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) with a [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following style and hope you should get what you are looking.

```
#dp {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 58px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest placing all the content inside div1 in a subdiv which you can give the css values from #field.

html:

```
<div id= "div1">
<div id="subdiv1">
<div id="field"><input placeholder="Type something...." ></div>
<div id="dp"><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#div1 {
 height:100px;
 width:200px;
 top:50%;
 border: 1px solid red;
 position: fixed;
}

#subdiv1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


#dp {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  background-color:#f00;
  width:100%;
}

#dp a {
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6kxz1c9L/

Answer (score 0):

Marts answer is correct for the styling but it doesn't show/hide on click. I've added some jQuery to make this happen:

```js
$("#field input").focus(function(){
    $("#dp").addClass('show_dp');
  });

  $("#field input").focusout(function(){
    $("#dp").removeClass('show_dp');
  });
```

```css
#div1 {
 height:100px;
 width:200px;
 top:15px;
 left:15px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 position: fixed;
}

#subdiv1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


#dp {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  background-color:#ff0;
  color:blue;
  width:100%;
  display: none;
  padding:4px 0;
}

#dp a {
  display:block;
}

.show_dp {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id= "div1">
  <div id="subdiv1">
    <div id="field">
      <input placeholder="Type something...." >
    </div>
    <div id="dp">
      <a>ITEM</a>
      <a>ITEM</a>
      <a>ITEM</a><a>ITEM</a>
      <a>ITEM</a>
      <a>ITEM</a>
      <a>ITEM</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```